# How to access admin dashboard for fauna dev, local database

Tags: docker, dashboard, faunadb

I'm trying to setup [fauna dev](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/integrations/dev) locally.

After installing the docker image, and running a persistent instance, I get this information showing in the terminal

```
Admin endpoint: 127.0.0.1:8444
API endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8443
API(plain) endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8445
Replica name: NoDC
FaunaDB is ready.
```

Pointing the browser to 127.0.0.1:8444 doesn't show a page

How do I access the admin dashboard locally?  Is the only way to navigate the database is through cli?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: through docker run, `docker run --rm --name faunadb -p 8443:8443 \
  -v ~/Documents/Database/Fauna:/var/lib/faunadb \
  fauna/faunadb`

Comment: The port syntax for docker run is host port:container port, to expose a port on the container's local network onto the host network. You're exposing port 8443, but you're trying to access port 8444 in your browser

Comment: Are you suggesting that this should work?, `docker run --rm --name faunadb -p 8443:8443 -p 8444:8444 \   -v ~/Documents/Database/Fauna:/var/lib/faunadb \   fauna/faunadb`. Why is this not working for me?

Comment: Do you mean the "Dashboard", as in what you get when you go to dashboard.fauna.com?  The Dashboard website is not included with the docker image.

Answer (score 3):

There is no admin Dashboard included in the Fauna Dev image.

The `Admin endpoint` that you listed is for internal tooling.

Typically, developers interact with Fauna Dev by using `fauna-shell`, or writing client applications that connect to the `API endpoint`.

Comment: This is the correct answer